# Does "MS db-lib source compatibility" have to be set to "yes" to connect to mssql with freetds?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, freetds

Before I try compiling freeTDS with msdblib enabled I'd like to ensure that's the what I need to do. Or is my issue elsewhere? I've seen lots of posts on configuration but no mentions of msdblib.

```
$tsql -S mssql -U user -P pass
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    OS error 61, "Connection refused"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

---

```
$odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/administrator/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

$tsql -C
    Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v1.00.48
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.48/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 7.3
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
                            OpenSSL: yes
                             GnuTLS: no
                               MARS: no
```

freetds.conf

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
        tds version = 7.3
```

...

```
# A typical Microsoft server
[mssql]
        host = 10.x.x.x
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.3
```

odbc.ini

```
[mssql]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Servername          = mssql
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: Resinstalling freetds with

    brew install freetds --with-msdblib

did not help :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the `--with-msdblib` option of freetds is required for MS SQL access but I was able to connect using the host name and instance. But first I had to find out the instance names, which can be done by `tsql -LH xxx.xx.xxx.xxx`. For some reason I couldn't connect with host name and port, i had to use host name and instance. Always read the documentation, y'all! Only took me 5 hours.